# How do you get World Edit enabled on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I'm considering making a map for me and my friends to play when I can and I feel like world edit would help speed things up alot. However I can't figure out how to enable it or if you need mods for it.

Is world edit vanilla or do you need mods? If you do need mods whats the official site for it? If it's vanilla how do you activate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[World Edit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit) I believe is the mod you are talking about. Vanilla Minecraft certainly doesn't have the same power or mechanics as this mod introduces.

It has instructions listed on the page:

> 1. Install Minecraft Forge or Fabric.
> 2. Download WorldEdit from this page.
> 3. Put the WorldEdit mod file into your mods folder.

There are also some YouTube videos on the page of some simple tutorials.

Minecraft Forge can be downloaded [here](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/).

---

**Outside** of the game, there is [McEdit](https://www.mcedit.net/), which is a "saved game editor for Minecraft".  It is an external program that you can use to modify a world file.